# How to implement 2 way encryption with either PHP or mySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, encryption, oauth

I am trying to securely store OAuth tokens and keys, and I know best practice is to encrypt these and treat them like user passwords. How can I do that while still being able to decrypt them and use them to make API calls to, say, twitter (I simply hash my passwords, which won't work for OAuth keys, as hashing is 1 way)?

I am open to doing it either in mySQL or PHP, so I would appreciate examples in either, or pros/cons of each approach.

Comment: Depending on your php skills, but you should look for [Crypt](http://lv.php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php) in php

Comment: Please do your research before implementing anything with this. There are many gotchas and this can easily backfire. http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/05/why-isnt-my-encryption-encrypting.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the mcrypt library in PHP (http://php.net/manual/en/book.mcrypt.php), it has support for all major cryptographic algorithms. I suggest you use AES-128, this is kind of the industry standard. Just make sure you store your key in a secure location. You can then encrypt your data, convert it to base64 and store that in your database. Whenever you need to use the data, just retrieve it from the database and apply the inverse operations.

I'm not familiar with how MySQL works exactly. Maybe there is a possibility to store data encrypted and have it store your key somewhere secure for you?

From a security point of view, the PHP method would be better though, because data going to and coming from your database is still encrypted.

Please don't use the XOR cypher, it is laughable at best. A single leaked plain-ciphertext pair will reveal your complete key (`plaintext XOR ciphertext = key`). This only provides perfect security when used as a [one-time pad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_time_pad). Of course you can't use this, because now you have to use a different key for every piece of data **and** somehow have to securely store all those one-time pads. Maybe you could use some encryption for that ;) ...? (insert infinite loop here).